# Does SAP HANA cloud support the R language?

Tags: r, hana

I am investigating SAP HANA cloud http://www.sap.com/pc/tech/cloud.html

The SAP HANA documents suggest that the R language works in SAP HANA. However when I tried it in the cloud, I get "insufficient privilege: Not authorized".

Comment: You should probably submit this as an answer, instead of editing your question.  Even if it might change in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It supports `R`, check this out: http://help.sap.com/hana/SAP_HANA_R_Integration_Guide_en.pdf.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have the 'Create R Script' role assigned to your user.

Check the roles [here](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/20/f674e1751910148a8b990d33efbdc5/content.htm)

In Hana Studio, this is done in the 'System' tab, under the 'Security' folder, then 'Users'.

Answer (score 1):

As of 6th November, 2014, it does not support R language but might do so in future.